# How to have a variable number of user inputs based on the first user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a program that calculates the average of a student, and I want input to be created based on the user input, for example: if the user types 5, it creates 5 input.

```
print('Average of students')

def student_average():
    while True:
        try:
            # I want to create inputs depending on the user's input in the following question:
            number_of_qualifications = int(input('What is the number of qualifications?: '))
            qualification_1 = float(input('What is the first qualification?: '))
            qualification_2 = float(input('What is the second qualification?: '))
            qualification_3 = float(input('What is the third qualification?: '))
            qualification_4 = float(input('What is the fourth qualification?: '))
            break
        except:
            print('This is not an option')
    sum = (qualification_1 + qualification_2 + qualification_3 + qualification_4)
    average = (sum / 4)
    print(average)

student_average()
```

Comment: You can create a loop for the number_of_qualifications entered and store qualifications into an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a loop.  I've removed the try/except, you can add that back in if you want.

```
def student_average():
    number_of_qualifications = int(input('What is the number of qualifications?: '))
    sumx = 0
    for _ in range(number_of_qualifications):
        sumx += float(input('What is the next qualification?: '))
    return sumx / number_of_qualifications

print(student_average())
```

Comment: may I know how do you implement try-except in a for-loop? If an exception occurs, the loop still increases by 1 so 1 data point is lost, so I cannot resolve this

Comment: You can put the `try`/`except` inside the for loop.

Comment: would you show me how please? Try with 5 inputs: 10, 20, 30, aa (exception), 40, 50. The average should be 30, but I'm unable to input the last one (50)

Comment: `while True`/`try`/`input`/`break`/`except`/`print`.

Comment: that solution is while-loop, NOT for-loop. I think it's only possible in while-loop

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your codes, so the try-except feature is preserved

```
def student_average():
    total, c = 0,0
    number_of_qualifications = int(input('What is the number of qualifications?: '))
    while True:
        try:
            # I want to create inputs depending on the user's input in the following question:
            total += float(input(f'{c+1} What is the qualification?: '))
            c += 1
            if c == number_of_qualifications:
                break
        except:
            print('This is not an option')
    average = (total / number_of_qualifications)
    print(average)
    
print('Average of students')
student_average()
```

Output:

```
Average of students
What is the number of qualifications?:  3
1 What is the qualification?:  4
2 What is the qualification?:  5
3 What is the qualification?:  a
This is not an option
3 What is the qualification?:  6
5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use "sum" as a variable, because it is a Python reserved word. If it has been used before, you have to restart the Kernel.

```
def student_average():
    cnt = 1
    total_list = []
    number_of_qualifications = int(input('What is the number of qualifications?: '))
    while len(total_list) < number_of_qualifications:
        try:
            # I want to create inputs depending on the user's input in the following question:
            total_list.append(float(input(f'{cnt}. What is the qualification?: ')))
            cnt += 1
        except:
            print('This is not an option')
    return (sum(total_list) / number_of_qualifications)
    
print('Average of students =', student_average())
```

Output

```
What is the number of qualifications?:  5
1. What is the qualification?:  10
2. What is the qualification?:  20
3. What is the qualification?:  30
4. What is the qualification?:  aa
This is not an option
4. What is the qualification?:  40
5. What is the qualification?:  50
Average of students = 30.0
```